# I can't figure out why my linux device can't connect to my windows server

Tags: python, linux, windows, sockets, networking

I have two device : a linux device and a windows device.

I want to connect my linux device to a windows device via socket. I made a little basic program in python that works fine only if I connect linux to linux but it doesn't works linux to windows. My windows server is only listening and my linux device get timeout because it can not connect. Any idea?

```
#windows code
MY_HOST = socket.gethostname()
PORT = int(sys.argv[1]) # usually 5050
serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind((MY_HOST,PORT))
print("listening....")

serverSocket.listen()
conn, addr = serverSocket.accept() # accept new connection
print("new connection: "+str(addr))

#client code
SERVER_HOST = sys.argv[1] # ip of windows machine
PORT = int(sys.argv[2])  # same port with windows machine usually 5050
clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((SERVER_HOST,PORT))
```

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Likely a firewall setting on the Windows machine is blocking incoming connections

Comment: It can be true, but i can do nothing because corporation stuff. Any idea how to see if this thing is true?

Comment: @Fredi just perform a port scan against your Windows computer, using nmap for example.

Comment: on server you can always use `MY_HOST = "0.0.0.0"` to use all available connections

Comment: @furas I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: @viilpe I got 135,139,445,2701,3389 open ports. Can I use one of these? Edit: I tried to use one of them, I got this error : OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. How can I open a specific port on Windows machine?

Comment: open ports mean that they are used by some services and you can't use them. But you should check your code with other common ports - first with `80` for `HTTP`,

Comment: @furas, thank you a lot for your advices. Also, I tried to listen on port 80 but it doesn't work for me

Comment: it seems you have blocked it by firewall and you would have to turn off firewall. OR you would have to change settings in firewall.